# How do I send email to subscriber's clients as though it was sent from subscriber? C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a subscription based website that will allow subscribers to send emails to their customers. How do I send email to customers as though it was sent from the subscribers email. Is this possible?

Comment: ANYTHING is possible.

Comment: Do you say you want to spoof your subscribers mail address? Can't you just send from your mail but in the subscriber's name?

Comment: You send the email with their address in the `From` header to a server that has been configured to allow such relaying.